# Listview custom adapter notify parent activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have created a listview that sits inside a larger activity (the list view fills half the screen, with inputs/buttons above it). This listview uses a custom adapter to draw the row views.

Inside the row view is a button, which when clicked/tapped i want the activity to handle, and not the adapter. However i don't know how inside the adapter class, i can tell it to use the activity. Since it's OOP, im assuming i have to pass some sort of reference to the activity when setting up the adapter (rather than hardcoding the parent activity into the adapter).

I had a simlier issue with sharing a dataset between the activity and adapter (i wanted the adapter to use an arraylist from the activity), however i couldn't solve that one either so i ended up passing the arraylist through as a duplicate into the adapter. So i would hope working out the click listener, will also mean i can get rid of that duplicate data having to be created?

All the code is pretty simple, but here's a rough outline:

**Setting the list adapter & declaring dataset (this is the activity dataset, not the adapter)**

```
numbersListAdapter = new NumberListAdapter(this);
numbersList.setAdapter(numbersListAdapter);
this.selectedContacts = new HashMap<Long, HashMap<String, String>>();
```

**Adding entry into activity data set and adding to the adapter dataset**

```
HashMap<String, String> tempa = new HashMap<String,String>();
tempa.put("name", name);
tempa.put("number", number);
this.selectedContacts.put(contactID, tempa);

this.numbersListAdapter.addEntry(contactID, tempa);
```

**The adapters add entry**

```
public void addEntry(Long id, HashMap<String, String> entry) {  

        entry.put("contactID", id.toString());      

        this.selectedNumbers.add(entry);

        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

**The adapters constructor**

```
public NumberListAdapter(Context context) {

        selectedNumbers = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
```

Please note: this is my first attempt at this stuff. I've never done android, java and very, very little OO programming. So i already know the code is most likely inefficient and quite terrible. But i've got to learn somehow :)

**EDIT**

Ok so i realised ive been a little silly and i just needed to use the context passed into the adapter to reference the parent activity. However i still ain't getting it. Heres the code:

**The constructor for the adapter**

```
numbersListAdapter = new NumberListAdapter(this);
```

**The variable declaration and constructor method**

```
public class NumberListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> selectedNumbers;

    private Context parentActivity;



    public NumberListAdapter(Context context) {

        parentActivity = (Context) context; 

        selectedNumbers = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
```

**The listener**

```
Button theBtn = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.actionRowBtn);
            theBtn.setOnClickListener(this.parentActivity);
```

I get two messages from eclipse, the first occurs when i comment out the listener and i get
`The value of the field NumberListAdapter.parentActivity is not used`

Once i add the listener in i get

`The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (Context)`

Obviously im doing something wrong.  Probably quite a silly mistake again too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get callback when row of the listview is clicked you can use

> [numbersListAdapter.setOnitemitemClickLiistener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29)

But if you need a button inside each row to be clicked you will have to override the

getView function of your adapter and then set the onclicklistener of the button individually

Edit:
Typecast the Context to Activity

```
theBtn.setOnClickListener((YourActivity)this.parentActivity);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i've already done all that, i have a custom list row view, and i know how to set listeners. My problem is i want the click listener to be the activity which the list (and list adapter) is inside of, i dont know how to reference the parent activity from the adapter. But thanks for your reply

Comment: I've literally just thought of this. It only just occurred to me that i pass "this" into the constructor in the activity, so obviously the context being passed through is the activity. I'm just going to try it now (should work). Can't believe how stupid i have been not to realise that (like i said, first time in Java/Android and first  time trying to stick to OOP structure). But thank you all the same

Comment: Hi nandeesh, hopefully your still monitoring Stackoverflow for questions. If i post some code up can you tell me where im going wrong with saving and using the context, im clearly doing something wrong

Comment: sure. If not me someone will :)

Comment: Thanks nandeesh, ive edited my question with an update at the bottom (everything after EDIT). I'm sure its a silly mistake im making